# After reinstalling Atom text editor I lost a lot of core functionalities

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, atom-editor

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I reinstalled Atom text editor  (I installed it by following instructions @ Atom GitHub ). I am using 64-bit version. I lost a lot of features such as searching specific characters (CTRL+F), settings (packages, themes, etc...CTRL+,), I can no longer change document language, etc...for example if I want to open settings (CTRL+,) it opens empty config file - screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Try it: sudo apt-get purge atom. And install again.

Comment: @ArthurOlenberg Doesn't seem to fix problem. I tried to reinstall it in many ways, now even in the one you suggested, and still same problem. Are you using Ubuntu 14.04? Could you try to reinstall it (dont worry about packages they will remain) and see if maybe it's problem with current version of Atom.

Comment: Yes, I have Xubuntu 14.04. I reinstalled the atom editor earlier. And I have not encountered such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All user Atom settings live inside `~/.atom` directory. By removing this directory and starting Atom again it will be recreated with default settings and therefore it will fix this problem. Simply run `rm -rf ~/.atom`. This works assuming you are using some Linux distribution such as Ubuntu, probably will work for Mac too.